# What does this TCL/Tk code do?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I found this pie menu code for TCL/Tk here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/15400

There is a line of code I don't understand:

```
-command0 {bind .c <Button-1> {}; %W delete __pm; incr cnt} \
```

What does it mean? I think this happens: the global variable cnt is incremented. All items with the tag __pm will be removed from the canvas. This all happens if the mouse button is clicked. 
But this doesn't really make sense does it?

Comment: In the example, it just does unbinds the Button-1 event, removes the piemenu and increments the cnt. As it is bound to -command0, this is probably the action for the topmost section of the menu, while -command1 is the action attached to the 1st section. Not sure why it increments the cnt, basically just counts the total numbers of pie menus, as far as i can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense if you actually run the demo, which demonstrates pie menus with a varying number of buttons. Clicking the central "button" labelled "Ok" will delete the pie menu. Note that this central text element is item 0. `%W` is short-hand for the pathname of the window relating to the Tk event that fired. Incrementing the `cnt` (count) will cause the next pie menu to be created to have a different number of "button" elements.